# How can i get information from JSON dictionary in java

Tags: java, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary on a website in form of json which looks for example like this:

```
"types":[{
    "id":"0",
    "name":"value1"
    },{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"value2"
    },{
    "id":"2",
    "name":"value3"
    }]
```

I cant find any useful example of a method that could help me retrieve that information and put it in, for example, a string array.
Maybe anyone of you come across same problem please help!

P.S. I tried method like [simplest way to read json from a URL in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java) with no success.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911558/java-deserializing-json-structure-to-mapstring-object?rq=1 doesn't help?

Comment: it loos like i am not smart enough to make use of link you have privided, i do not see any connection between those two topics..

Comment: It looks to me that your question is then unrelated to your problem. Your comment to Quoi's appropriate answer, which is very similar to the one in the link I gave, shows it also. I'd advise you give more information if you expect people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is array of json object value whose key is `types`. You can use json-java library like `gson, jackson,flexjson etc..` to parse this json object and achieve your required result.

GSON Example -

```
JsonElement jElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
JsonObject  jObject = jElement.getAsJsonObject();
jObject = jObject.getAsJsonObject("types");
```

Or you can use pojo class like -

```
public class Type {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  ...
}

gson.fromJson(jsonString, Type.class);
```

Refer [java docs](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html).

Comment: quoi thanks for your relpy, mian problem is that i can't read jsonString, i believe it is beacause of link under which it is *.jsp